# How to access a Gmail message metadata in the onTriggerFunction function?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, permissions, gmail, add-on

I am creating a Gmail add-on and want to get **bcc, cc, to and from** fields once the user clicks on an email.

I have defined `onTriggerFunction` in the manifest and added metadata scope. But couldn't get emails under the event object. Is there any way to get related emails without reading the email message?

Manifest gmail object

```
"gmail": {
  "contextualTriggers": [{
    "unconditional": {
    },
    "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
  }]
}
```

Trigger function look like:

```
function onGmailMessage(e) { 
   Logger.log(e.gmail); 
}
```

output:

```
{
  messageId=msg-f:1670823024080259424, 
  threadId=thread-f:1670823024080259424, 
  accessToken=AN68bGZPxBW2UNSRNU38c6nj4qPPEqraqzIPdS 
}
```

Metadata scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata
```

Comment: Did you follow the contextual trigger steps from the [guide](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui#contextual_trigger_function)? Could you show us how it looks like?

Comment: please, include it in the question, comments are not the place for the code, thank you. Also, please, read the guide I mentioned above.

Comment: yes, already read, want to access bcc, to and cc emails via metadata, without requesting `read` access

Comment: And did you try to implement the function as described in the guide (note that the example says *in this case* - it shows both scopes in action at once)? Was there an error? Were you not able to get the metadata?

Comment: I don't want to call GmailApp, get the message, and read the content. Want to simply get toRecipients, ccRecipients and bccRecipients via [event object](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#gmail_event_object) which is passed to the trigger function, the problem was I am not getting those fields, check my log.

Comment: You misunderstand what the flow here is - `GmailApp` is the way to go to get the information about the message metadata or not. Please, reread the guide on contextual triggers. If you don't need content - don't read it. The metadata scope is completely sufficient to read the message metadata. The only data you get from the even object [is described here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#gmail_event_object).